# Why does glm give a wrong result when transformating a 3D vector?

Tags: c++, glm-math

```
glm::vec4 x = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec4 y = glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec4 z = glm::vec4(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec4 t(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glm::mat4 rot(x, y, z, t);
glm::vec4 test = rot * glm::vec4(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

The "test" varible should be (0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f, 1.0f) but the returned result is (0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f). Is this a bug of glm?

Comment: "*The "test" varible should be (-10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) but the returned result is (10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f).*" Neither answer is correct, given the input matrix and the input vertex. This matrix clearly does some form of flip around the Y axis, so a vector with only an X component should become a vector with a Z component.

Comment: Thanks Nicol Bolas, I made a mistake. The "test" variable should be (0, 0, -10, 1). But the output is (0, 0, 10, 1)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are assuming that the four vectors `x`, `y`, `z`, and `t` are "row vectors", but it appears that they are "column vectors". Therefore, the matrix `rot` is most likely:

```
x  y  z  t
__________
0  0 -1  0
0  1  0  0 
1  0  0  0
0  0  0  1
```

Which when multiplied with column vector:

```
10
 0
 0
 1
```

Gives column  vector:

```
 0
 0
10
 1
```

EDIT: Fixed inverted terminology

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the actual result be `(0, 0, 10, 2)`? Essentially, matrix times a vector means a linear combination of matrix columns with coefficients from a vector. So, in your example

```
rot * glm::vec4(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
```

is equivalent to

```
10.0f * x + 0.0f * y + 0.0f * z + 1.0f * t
```